# MVC3 Bind validation in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I spent a good amount of time on google and cannot find the answer.

Instead of having an attribute in the model class like

```
public class MyModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Can I add the Required requirement in the controller instead of attribute?

I am expecting something like ValidationProvider.Add(some model properties, some constraints)
Have anyone done that before?

Comment: thanks for your reply.... but I am so sure that it is the only way out in my situation.  Is there anything like ValidationProvider.Add(some property, some contraint) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah sure you can (in controller method):

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Name))
  ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Name is required");

if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  return View();
```

But really you should use the attributes, or implement `IValidatableObject` on your model class.  Keeps things nicely separated.

Comment: This is not something I am looking for.  I wanna bind a validation which mean it will work on the front end as well.  The code here is forcefully push an error in the validation.

Comment: Okay - well it's always helpful to include that in the question ;)

In short - yes - it can be done - but you will need to implement your own ModelMetadataProvider - I can't really give you code for that but I'm sure if you google around and read MVC articles and stuff you'll figure it out.

Comment: Andras, thanks for your reply.  I really spend a good deal of time to google it.  It will be great if you can post a link for that.  I may search in a wrong direction.

Comment: sorry @KennethLam there's no ready-rolled solution I know of, and the code to do such a thing would simply take too long and make an answer that's too long to read.  I strongly suggest getting hold of the MVC source, and looking at the existing provider to see how you can extend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5 you can use the required attribute in the field itself (in the view). Also consider the FluentValidation for .Net (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). Or you can use knockoutjs framework to control required fields.

Comment: The logic needs to be in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't because if you do, the attribute won't be required at the data layer and there will be no corresponding database constraint.

Comment: It has nothing to do with database.  Model can be a custom create model.